# How to set from when sending email via smtp server with using microsoft c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, send

How to set "from" when sendin email via smtp server with using microsoft c#

if you look this image you will understand what i mean

i use the code below for sending emails

[image]

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(srUserEmail);

                    string srBody = "bla bla bla";
 mail.From = new MailAddress("PokemonCraft.Announcement@pokemoncraft.com");
                        mail.Subject = "bla bla bla";
     mail.Body = srBody;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Host = "xxx.xx.xx.xx";
                    smtp.Port = xxx;


                    smtp.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your email address like this:

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("PokemonCraft <PokemonCraft.Announcement@pokemoncraft.com>");
```

The MailAddress object should recognize that the part inside `<>` tags is an email address, whereas the part preceding that is the name of the person or business sending the email.

Answer (score 7):

Pass a second argument to the `MailAddress` constructor:

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("Announcement@pokemoncraft.com", "Some Display Name")
```